# Возврат результата в Ajax.BeginForm

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, mvc

Не могу получить результат работы вызываемого метода UpdateMenuNews, то есть по идеи параметры  @Html.LabelFor и @Html.TextBoxFor должны обновить значения после вызова, но этого не происходит.

```
    @model Models.MenuPanelNews
    @using (Ajax.BeginForm("UpdateMenuNews", "News", new AjaxOptions { OnSuccess = "ValidateInsertForm(data)" }))
    {
         @Html.LabelFor(x => x.PopularName)
         @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PopularName)
         <input class="update_button" type="submit" value="Найти" />
    }
```

метод

```
[HttpPost]
    public Models.MenuPanelNews UpdateMenuNews(Models.MenuPanelNews MenuPanelNews)
    {
        Models.Db_Initializer _InitializerPageNews = new Models.Db_Initializer();
        MenuPanelNews = _InitializerPageNews.GetMenuPanelNews(MenuPanelNews);
        return MenuPanelNews;
    }
```

Может я что путаю или упустил что то, **но я даже не смог найти похожего примера для понимания**. Заранее спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуете обернуть ваш код Razor код в PartialView, и возвращать из метода это PartialView:

```
return PartialView("PartialView", MenuPanelNews);
```

Comment: спасибо помогло